# How to disable windows 10 touchscreen gestures?

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

I need to disable all touchscreen edge gestures so an application can run in 'kiosk mode' without the user accessing things like virtual desktops or action center / notification center. However the user still needs to be able to use the touchscreen to click the screen as with a mouse. There is 'assigned access' on certain windows operating systems which mau help, but not on this device which has windows 10 home. The device is a 7" linx tablet running a 'Goodix' brand touchscreen but ideally i need an answer that works with any windows touchscreen device.

Comment: You can uninstall the device itself, that would disable the gestures, more information about the device would be required to provide different suggestions and/or answers.

Comment: Any update on this? It is frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

official way to disable touchscreen gestures is only available on pro / enterprise / iot windows. home edition users will be out of luck.

```
gpedit.msc
Local Computer Policy
 Computer Configuration
  Administrative templates
   Windows Components
    EdgeUI
     Allow edge swipe = Disabled
```

Completely Disable Action Center in Windows 10

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
create new DWORD DisableNotificationCenter=1
```

Disable New Action Center Sidebar and Restore Previous UI

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell
UseActionCenterExperience DWORD= 0 ( default = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to remove the swipe for action center for a while and not finding any solutions anywhere online. I finally was able to achieve exactly how I wanted it to behave. Swiping from the right edge does not activate but the button still remains in the taskbar if i do want to use it. All I did was modify the registry here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\LockDown\AllowEdgeSwipe

I changed "Value" from 1 to 0, rebooted and good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this recently and as far as I could see it **there is no official way** (for now) to disable it in **Windows 10**, taking into account that this question [was asked on official forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-to-disable-touchscreen-gestures-on-windows-10/3ff7654e-c90e-41d7-b2d1-1dfbba0812fd) on **August 26, 2015** and the solution Microsoft representative provided since then (and till **December 5, 2015**) was only for touch pad (you can initiate this "switch windows mode" thing using three-finger swipe on touch pad as well), kind of registry changes, but it is not disabling touch *screen* gestures from the side of the screen.

What makes it even more frustrating is that it *was* [possible to disable](https://www.victoriawebsolutions.com/turn-off-gesture-swipe-windows-8/) this gesture in **Windows 8.1** back in **September 16, 2014**!

[image: Disable swipe from the left on Windows 8.1]

Hopefully Microsoft will add it back to **Windows 10** in upcoming [Redstone](http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/7/8364355/microsoft-redstone-windows-updates) release (fingers crossed).

Comment: Any update on this? It is frustrating!